# Is there any reversing function for Wordpress "esc.." functions?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using the standart "esc_html" in Wordpress for insert data (textarea) to the db.

All works nice but how can I reverse the text?

For example:

I insert the text - ***You ready?! Let's go!***

And in the db it's as I expected save it as - `You ready?! Let&#039;s go!`

Later, when I tried to display this text in my tooltip it's also display the text as `You ready?! Let&#039;s go!`

Please, I would like to know if there is any reverse for this function since I tried to use htmlspecialchars_decode() and realized it's not the same function.

Thanks!

Comment: Question: why are you escaping the content before inserting it into the database?

Comment: @cabrerahector I escaped from HTML because i dont want any chance for sql injection when user inser a data to db..
EDIT -- right after your answer, a little search come to this -> https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/25947/wpdb-insert-do-i-need-to-prepare-against-sql-injection
so, just to be sure, when i'm using standart wpdb (also any function by wp like "wp_insert_post" and so on) I don't need to escape or to be worry about sql injection? all i need to do it's just escape when I display the data from the db? (on the select method only)?

Thanks

Comment: In that case you should _sanitize_ the data before saving it to DB, not _escape_ it. You escape it when you're going to display it on screen.

Comment: The answer from the link you shared is correct. If you're using the `insert()` method from the `$wpdb` object or [wp_insert_post()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/) to write data to the DB all the sanitization is done for you. Otherwise if you're writing a custom query you'll want to use the `prepare()` method from the `$wpdb` object. Again, don't escape when saving to DB. You do that when you're going to show said data in the browser.

Comment: @cabrerahector Thank you! I would really come to serious problems if I did not get that answer..

Comment: You're welcome, @user3095384. I've posted my comments as an answer below for you to accept it if you want to. There I expanded a little on the whole escape vs sanitize thing for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: generally speaking, you don't *escape* data when saving it to the database. You *sanitize* it. (And so you don't really need to worry about "reverting" the content from esc_* functions).

You sanitize the input data when you're about to insert it into the database to prevent SQL injection attacks. If you're using the [insert()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#INSERT_row) method from the `$wpdb` object or the [wp_insert_post()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/) function to create a new post/page, then the sanizitation is done for you automatically.

If you're writing a custom query (eg. `$wpdb->query( "INSERT INTO table VALUES('a string', 'another string', '2018-09-21 10:35:52')" );`) then you need to use the [prepare()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks) method to sanitize the query before running it (eg. `$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( "INSERT INTO table VALUES(%s, %s, %s)", array($string1, $string2, $date_string) ) );`).

When you're about to display the data on screen use any of the different esc_* functions to make sure nothing malicious is being printed on screen (like `<script>alert('Hello!');</script>`).

Answer (score 3):

There is a PHP function for this!

```
$string = "You ready?! Let&#039;s go!";
$decodedString = htmlspecialchars_decode($string, ENT_QUOTES);
```

> Decoded String: 'You ready?! Let's go!'

[Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php)

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried wp_specialchars_decode() ?
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_specialchars_decode/